# T-SQL convert varchar yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.nnnnnn into datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

This is in MS SQL Server.

I have a varchar in the format yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.nnnnnn

For example: 2010-09-17-20.52.31.870000

I want to convert this into a datetime... but ISDATE function in MSSQL says that is not a valid date and CONVERT won't work.  Is there a way to use the convert function so that I can tell it what format the date is in?

I also want to check first that it is a valid date since the varchar input may contain nothing or it may contain an invalid date.

For example, invalid data of 2010-xx-r7-99.53esdfd.31.870000... I would skip that data and not even try to convert.

Comment: '2010-09-17-20.52.31.870000' is not a valid datetime. You have an extra dash before the time portion

Comment: I guess that is why ISDATE doesn't recognize it, but that is the data being given to me.  I double-checked and it is a dash before the time portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, SQL Server 2005 only supports milliseconds up to 3 digits, so you could replace the periods with colons, and grab the left and right portions (ignoring the hyphen between the day and hours) and come up with something like this:

```
DECLARE @myDate varchar(50)
SET @myDate = '2010-09-17-20.52.31.870000'

PRINT isdate(left(@myDate, 10) + ' ' + 
 replace(substring(@myDate, 12, 12), '.', ':'))  -- Should print '1'

PRINT cast(left(@myDate, 10) + ' ' + 
    replace(substring(@myDate, 12, 12), '.', ':') as datetime)
```

... which will effectively give you 870 milliseconds

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

The [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard separates the date and time with the letter `T`.  Maybe that's all it needs to convert successfully?  Some conversion implementations accept a space there too.  I've never seen a hyphen there.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  Maybe I can work with that... replace the 11th character with a T...?

Comment: @metanaito -- I tried replacing the 11th character with a T, and that didn't work for `isdate` or casting

Comment: Thanks, yes, I guess there are other problems with the input as well like you and others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change the punctuation a bit to make it work, and reduce the precision from microseconds to millisecond. This works:

```
convert(datetime, '2010-09-17 20:52:31.870', 121)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting in is a bit wonky, but this works (tested):

```
DECLARE @temp as varchar(50)

SET @temp = '2010-09-17-20.52.31.870'

SET @temp = replace(@temp,'.',':')
set @temp = stuff(@temp,11,1,'T')
set @temp = stuff(@temp,20,1,'.')

select @temp

select cast(@temp as datetime)
```

NB I cut off the extra `0`s, you could do this with substring if there really are those extra ones.